# Filtering results using SQL Where Exists()

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, exists

I am using software that will **only** allow me to enter the **WHERE**... portion of an SQL statement.

So I can use the EXISTS () statement in the where clause...

however,

this query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Left([PR].[WBS1],5)&"-000" AS WBS1
FROM PR
GROUP BY Left([PR].[WBS1],5), Right([PR].[WBS1],3), PR.Status
HAVING ((Right(PR.WBS1,3)<>'000') And ((PR.Status)='A') And (Count(PR.Org))>1)
```

...returns **78 records.**

yet,

virtually the same query with WHERE EXISTS...

```
SELECT PR.WBS1 FROM PR WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT DISTINCT Left([PR].[WBS1],5)&"-000" AS WBS1
FROM PR
GROUP BY Left([PR].[WBS1],5), Right([PR].[WBS1],3), PR.Status
HAVING ((Right(PR.WBS1,3)<>'000') And ((PR.Status)='A') And (Count(PR.Org))>1)

)
```

...returns all **31,114 records**.

**And I really don't understand why.**

What am I doing wrong; can someone explain that to me, please?

edit: What can I put here that would return the same 78 records:

```
SELECT * FROM PR WHERE (

     ?

)
```

The accounting software I'm using only allows me to edit the 'where' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS` returns `TRUE` if the subquery inside the parentheses returns at least 1 row  or `FALSE` if the subquery does not return any row.

In your case the subquery returns 78 rows, so `EXISTS` returns `TRUE`.

So your 2nd query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT PR.WBS1 FROM PR WHERE 1=1 -- any boolean expression that returns TRUE
```

or simply:

```
SELECT PR.WBS1 FROM PR
```